# ListView name not access in xaml.cs

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have pivot with listView in my xaml. ListView has name "NoteItems:
I cannot write full my xaml code, so I gave link to documents.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wcbvdex25zV8_AYWjLfLC9fs9T1XsSo9

But xaml.cs has error "The name "NoteItems" does not exist in the current context" in this string:

```
            NoteItems.DragOver += OnStepsListViewDragOver;
        (NoteItems.ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged += OnStepsCollectionChanged;
```

Comment: can you provide whole xaml ?

Comment: @FastJack Where I can write my xaml code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your item resides in an ItemTemplate, so you can't access it via CodeBehind or anywhere outside the scope.

Think of it this way: at design time, there are no items and during runtime there are *n*!

So which item you wish your source to access? -> impossible.

what *could* work is that you name your pivot and work your way down to the items.. but I would need more information about your xaml structure to give a definite answer on that.

Comment: Where I can write my full xaml code?

Comment: just intend with 4 spaces with your favourite text editor and post here ;) ... as ANWER, not as comment ;)